# How do you define and contrast すっぱり すっぽり さっぱり and すっかり

Tags: nuances, adverbs, synonyms, onomatopoeia

すっぱり
すっぽり
さっぱり
すっかり

My dictionary is not leaving me with a clear understanding of how to distinguish these words, their origins, their connotations, or the contexts they're usually used in.

They all share some sense of the English "completely", but how are they not alike?

Comment: Related：https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1507/45489

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each has multiple nuances. I will write typical meanings and example sentences that are often used.

### すっぱり

1. Cutting things sharply.

> えだをすっぱり切り落とした。
>
> I hacked off a branch.

2. The act of doing something decisively.

> 旅行の計画をすっぱりとあきらめた。
>
> I gave up the travel plan. (just like that).

### すっぽり

1. How things fit in and out.

> 子供がすっぽり入るくらいの大きさです。
>
> It's big enough to completely fit a child inside.

2. The state of covering the whole.

> 街全体が雪ですっぽりとおおわれた。
>
> The whole city was completely covered with snow.

### さっぱり

1. Discomfort and feeling of discontent are completely gone and you feel good about the situation.

> 友達と仲直りして、さっぱりした気持ちになった。
>
> I made up with my friend and felt refreshed.

> シャワーしてさっぱりした！
>
> I took shower and (now) I feel refreshed!

2. Personality, taste, smell is not persistent.

> 友達はさっぱりした性格で、一緒にいて気が楽だ。
>
> My friends are easy-going and easy to be with.

> このドレッシングは、さっぱりしていておいしい。
>
> This dressing is refreshing and delicious.

3. さっぱり + negative form, "not at all".

> さっぱり思い出せない。
>
> I can't remember at all.

### すっかり

1. A situation where nothing is left.

> れいぞうこの中の食べ物がすっかりなくなってしまった。
>
> The food in the refrigerator is completely gone.

2. Being in a certain state completely.

> テストがあることをすっかり忘れていた。
>
> I completely forgot there was a test.

> もうすっかり秋だ。
>
> It's already completely autumn.