# Meaning of スポーンてしちゃった

Tags: meaning, translation, word-choice, usage

Context: Person A thinks she made a mistake in the play she was in and is afraid the director is made at her. When she goes to talk to the director she says

> えと、えと……！
> あたし、セリフがスポーンてしちゃったかな！？

I can't find any results on what スポーンて could mean. My best guys is that she "missed" or "forgot" but I'm not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

スポーン is a variant of [すっぽり](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%99%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BD%E3%82%8A/#jn-118837), meaning

> ２ 物がうまくはまりこむさま。また、はまっている物が抜けてしまうさま。「指がビール瓶の口に—（と）はまる」「**人形の首が—（と）とれてしまう**」

It basically expresses (1) something tightly fits in or (2) something that fits tightly gets taken out.

As for the use in the sentence, it means (2) and the bold example above is relevant. You can think スポーンした means スポーンと抜けた. Thus セリフがスポーンてした means *words slipped my mind completely*.

Another variant: すぽっ.

---

Related

- [How do you define and contrast すっぱり すっぽり さっぱり and すっかり](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/96236/45489)